# Can animation exports be longer than 10 seconds?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2

I'm exporting an animation to .avi and they all turn out to be 10 seconds long. Is there a way to change this? To have the animation play for a longer duration?

ArcGIS 10.2.2

Comment: Does the 10-second video contain all the animation? If it does, try reducing the frame duration to 1.0 second or larger. (default might be 0.1 second).

Comment: Where do I adjust this? I am not entirely sure if the animation contains everything as it is displaying a lot of points everywhere.